Why do advanced piano keyboards use thirds and sixths in their harmonies instead of fourths when using their duet harmony feature?
A long time ago, I got a Yamaha PsR-192 or 292, I forget which, and I discovered that not only could you play chord accompaniments on the left-hand side, such as when improvising or using its built-in styles and rhythms, but you could also use features like duet, trio, block, country, and octave.
One thing I've always wondered, was why the duet harmony always used a sixth below the root of a note instead of a fourth. For example, if I played Hot Cross Buns, while holding down the C note on the left-hand side, I'd hear
E4-C4, D4-G3, and C4-E3.

If I held the G note on the word cross instead, it would sound like this.
E4-C4, D4-B3, and C4-E3.

The reason that stood out to me was because I remember my elementary school teacher teaching us to play that song using recorders in G-major, but the harmony sounded like this.
B5-G5, A5-F#5, and G5-D5.

If I used the trio feature, it would most certainly use those notes, but it would also combine that of the duet at the same time.
E4-C4-G3, D4-B3-G3, and C4-G3-E3.

Are there any reasons for this? Thanks!

Any reason why you think it should be a 4th over a 3rd or 6th?

I'm not sure how "smart" the logic involved is, but if we were asking about humans making these choices, then we'd be talking about two concerns, doubling (e.g. when representing a C chord with only two notes, which do you leave out? or with 4 notes, which do you double?) and chord inversion (/making a bass line). Since the harmony note is lower, it's deciding which note goes in "the bass." For the G chord, it chose root position (at the expense of stepwise motion).

Parallel thirds sound a lot better than fourths and also preserve the major/minor tonality of the harmony, while fourths are neither major nor minor. Maybe that's saying the same thing twice.

I think this is what you are playing...

...where c) is your elementary school example transposed to C to make comparison easier. I put the pitches you played in normal sized note heads and the pitches the keyboard harmonizing feature supplied in small note heads.
Let's start with a few simple traditional, common practice era harmonization ideas.

A "minimal" approach to diatonic harmony is to harmonize using only the I and V chords. Special consideration needs to be given to scale degrees ^4 and ^6 (solfege FA and LA.) The two chord list can be expanded to harmonize ^4 and ^6 with an optional seventh chord V7 and a subdominant chord of either ii or IV. Our minimal chord palette is I and V supplemented with occasional V7, ii6, IV or similar chords.
In terms of relative motion parallel thirds and sixths can be used freely with no concern beyond the potential monotony of overuse.
In terms of dissonance and relative motion fourths require special treatment. There is no need to elaborate here, just understand that relatively speaking motion
and harmony in thirds and sixths is "easier" than that in fourths.
In three part writing the basic approach is to voice all three pitches of triadic harmony (we can gloss over details involving the V7 chord in three parts.) In two part writing emphasis is given to vertical harmonies of imperfect thirds and sixth, being more "sonorous" and giving a more obvious sense of major/minor tonal quality than the "empty" sound of perfect intervals of octave, fifths, and fourths.

We can only guess at what the keyboard software is actually doing, but we can make those educated guesses based on the harmony concepts I just laid out.
Example a) is the only one that seems complicated. In terms of complete triads the keyboard could have harmonized with G3, but by using C4 it uses the tonic pitch and doubles the chord root, both of which are fundamentally solid harmonization choices. The second chord with melody tone D4 by the minimal harmony approach would be a V, but you played a C in the base contradicts V. The obvious thing for the keyboard to do is assume you want a C chord and treat D4 as a passing tone. The question then remains what harmony pitch to add. An E would be the simple choice, but that would mean two dissonant pitches above your bass. Therefore harmonizing with G3 provides a partial C chord with only one dissonant tone. The third chord starts with you playing the C doubled, the obvious chord to use is I, but harmonizing with G3 would be "empty", so the more "sonorous" third/sixth is used. Also, if you look at only the keyboard supplied middle voice, you will notice it arpeggiates the I triad where the middle pitch of G3 is the common tone between the I and V chords which is nice and clear from both the harmonic and melodic perspectives.
Example b) is comparatively simple. In the two part chords "sonorous" thirds and sixths are used and the specific pitches selected form partial I chords. Where you played bass G on the second chord (the one with lyrics "cross") the melody tone is D4, the V chord is the obvious harmony choice, and filling in pitch B3 completes all three pitches of the triad.
Example c) is what your teacher showed you, so that is simply what they wanted to do. It's reasonable to describe that harmonizing lower part of C4 B3 G3 as pitches closest to the melody E4 D4 C4 fulfilling a I V I chord progression. In other words it is a two voice "slice" of the full triad harmony in close position voicing.
Example d) is simply the close position voicing of triadic harmony I V I where the top part is the melody E4 D4 C4.
The only aspect of these four examples that seems worth comparing is the difference between the third chord of b) and the third chord of c). In b) the choice apparently gives preference to the vertical aspect of the music and chooses a "sonorous" sixth over a smoother melodic line. In c) the opposite preference is taken and the smoother melody is taken rather than the vertical sound of a sixth. I assume this comparative point is the crux of your question, because it is the only place I see a clear disparity between thirds and sixths over fourths in harmonization.
